# APFS partition corrupted after Paragon Disk Manager has failed

Tags: mac, filesystems, data-recovery, boot-camp, apfs

I am using a MacBook Pro 16" with Big Sur with FileVault enabled and used Paragon Disk Manager (latest version) to resize Bootcamp partition in the 1TB Internal SSD of my Mac. However, operation failed and when I shutdown my Mac and try booting into macOS it didn't appear as startup disk. There wasn't any error messages given by Paragon.

It said something stating that process was failed. When I try to mount corrupted container I get:

> “com.apple.DiskManagement.disenter -119930868 error.”

I tried using Internet Recovery to use first aid and it failed immediately.

How can I recover partition or at least find out what's the actual problem. I can run commands using Internet Recovery.

Comment: More info may be useful… specific Mac, macOS version, FileVault, Paragon version, actual error message… etc. Presumably you took this most dangerous of steps without a backup, otherwise just restore from that.

Comment: It's a 16' MacBook Pro with Big Sur. FileVault is on. I used latest Paragon Hard Disk Manager, there wasn't any error messages given by Paragon. It said something stating that process was failed. When I try to mount corrupted container I get: com.apple.DiskManagement.disenter -119930868 error.

Comment: M1 or Intel? I need to know to tell you the answer

Comment: You can also just take the SSD out and get a adapter format it as APFS on another mac, put it back in and press command+r and select reinstall Mac OS

Comment: @EricPan It's Intel. Actually I want to recover the data rather than erasing partition as my last backup is out dated and I totally screwed up.

Comment: You can take it to a data recovery expert and pay them I guess, I don't know this. I only accidentally deleted my mac partition in windows but I got it reinstalled, its well different for you...

Comment: I actually managed to solve problem thanks to a post. It broke Bootcamp too but at least I have access to all of my files in the macOS partition. Post that helped me: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/386543/398972